# SQL order by RAND()

Tags: mysql, sql

Do not understand why order by `RAND()` will return records in random order? `RAND()` returns a value between 0 and 1, and I think we should order by a column name?

Appreciate if anyone could explain why order by `RAND()` will return rows in random order. Thanks.

BTW, I am using MySQL Workbench/MySQL.

thanks in advance,
Lin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ORDER BY RAND()` copies the whole table into a temporary table and adds a new column with a random value. Finally, it sorts the data by that column.

This of course, has an impact on performance, so it's not recommended.

For more information:

http://www.roberthartung.de/mysql-order-by-rand-a-case-study-of-alternatives/

http://wanderr.com/jay/order-by-slow/2008/01/30/

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=65177

Comment: thanks and if I want to randomly select 10 rows, how to implement by RAND()?

Comment: That would be SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10;